# How to skip html5 validations when clicking on SKIP button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, validation

I have button SUBMIT and SKIP on same page.When user click on submit all validation check and form submit that's good .

Issue is with SKIP button. How I skip validations when user click on SKIP button?

Answer (score 0):

Write javascript/jquery code to remove the `required` attribute from the relevant fields on clicking the `skip` button.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you want to create a reset type button, assuming you're using `form_for` or something that provides a local `f` var:

```
= f.button "Skip", type: :reset
```

Then in a javascript file that's loaded you want to attach to the click event for that button, I've written this in coffeescript (and accounting for turbolinks):

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->

  $("button[type=reset]").click ->
    form = $(@).closest("form")[0]
    form.reset()
    form.submit()
```

This will cause that button to both reset the form (ie. clear any values in it) and submit the form.

If JS is not enabled then the button will act like a standard HTML "reset" button (without submitting the form.